verbs: Difference between a Shared Completion Queue and a Shared Receive Queue?
I am trying to manage multiple Queue Pairs connections in the same thread. To do that, I can share the same Completion Queue with multiple Queue Pairs and poll it in a single thread.
I don't see what feature Shared Receive Queue add?

If you have multiple QPs without a shared receive queue (SRQ) then you need to post sufficient receive work requests to each QP separately, which multiplies the amount of memory needed (each QP needs enough receives posted to handle the worst case). With SRQ, all the QPs can draw from one queue of buffers, which means you just need to handle the worst case aggregate traffic.
Certainly this is not advantageous for all workloads or application designs, but it can be a big improvement for applications where a large workload is spread unpredictably over a large set of QPs (an NVMe over fabrics storage target would be a good example).

Thanks. Then, when using a SRQ, should I never post Receive Work Request to QP individually with ibv_post_recv(), but only use ibv_post_srq_recv(), which will virtually push a Work Request to all QPs ? Also, you say this is not advantageous. What is the drawback? Is it slower because of the sharing?

Shared Receive Queue(SRQ) is the technique that try to reduce the NIC memory footprint, which is important to the scalability(i.e. need more QPs).
Queue pairs(QP) usually consist of a send queue and a receive queue. But the usage of send queue and receive queue is not balanced. When we use RDMA read, RDMA write, or send operation, we post wqe(work queue element) to the send queue; but we only need to post relevant wqe to recv queue  when we use send/(send with imm)/(RDMA write with imm). It means that send queue is used more, and recv queue is used less. So SRQ means that we use a shared recv queue for multi send queues. According to a test performed by myself with perftest, the bandwidth is indeed reduced cause the sharing.
